# How to calculate real depth from disparity map

Tags: stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I know a function

```
             (Baseline*focal)
depth  =     ------------------
           (disparity*SensorSize)
```

when `focal/SensorSize = fx` in intrinsics[0][0], right?

But this calculated depth is always less than the real depth.
the real depth like:

```
             (Baseline*focal)
depth  =     ------------------
           ((disparity-bias)*SensorSize)
```

And I have 4 same cameras, when use camera0 and camera1 the bias is 4, but when use camera 2 and camera3 the bias is 5.
I don't know why!!!

Comment: There are lot of errors that can influence your measurements. How do you determine the correct bias to be 5 instead of 4? You have the right reference in the real world, so maybe you are compensating another error from calibration (in baseline or intrisics values... I can't know how you retrieve these values. For example... you may suppose that the 4 cameras have all the same intrisics, but it could be not true). And... if disparity is measured in pixel, an error of 1 pixel is the minimum absolute error I think.

Comment: 1. I have a laser rangefinder, this bias is calculate by comparison between the calculated depth and the value of laser rangefinder

Comment: 2. I use opencv for calibrate.

Comment: I know that don't have 2 camera with same intrinsics. If use opencv, the 2 intrinsics are same, and if use matlab, the 2 intrinsics are different. But which intrinsics I can use?